# Want to run sql file through VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I am trying to connect to the Sybase server through VBA and run the sql file that contains a set of sql lines (sometimes more than 60 lines).

I have written the code as below. However, it is giving me error that " There is an incorrect statement around '\'"

Please help.

```
Sub sqltest()

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.Open "DRIVER={Sybase ASE ODBC Driver};UID=" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 13).Value & ";pwd=" & ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 14).Value & ";NA=<server address> ; CommandTimeout = 50000 ;ConnectionTimeout = 50000; ConnectionIdleTimeout = 50000;Connection LifeTime = 50000;LoginTimeout = 50000;AlternateServers = <server address>;"
conn.Open

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
cmd.CommandText = "\\<IP address>\pag\OffShore PAG\Parallel Run\Reports\Sunil\Mymacros\sample macros\SQL NC DB.sql"

cmd.Execute
conn.Close

Set conn = Nothing
Set cmd = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: `CommandText` should get the *content* of the file - it does not take a file path. Try something like `cmd.CommandText = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject").opentextfile("yourPath Here").ReadAll()`

Comment: Hi Tim, Thanks for your help. however, i am getting another error while using this. I am not sure how to add the screenshot of the error here. The error says "Incorrect Syntax near declare".

Comment: I'm no Sybase user, but it would probably help to show the content of your SQL file.

Answer (score 0):

Why do it by VBA? I would do it manually using the "From other sources" in the "Data" ribbon menu item.

"From other sources"->"From Microsoft Query"->"".
Next specify your database, driver etc. and the SQL.

Comment: Hi, i want to write a macro, so that i can create a report from the retrieved data. Please help...